# How to use call function?

Tags: d3.js

Lets say I have some g elements of class line. So I can write:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll('.line');
lines.exit().remove();
lines.transition().append('text')
lines.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'line');
```

And then append('text') is called for each g.line element. What if I want to call custom function f instead of append? I guess this should use call function, but:
`lines.call(f)` will call f only once (with all data, but I want to launch f separately for each element)

Luckily found that this is possible, not sure if there is smth better:
lines.transition().each(function(datum, index) {
            renderDataLine(d3.select(this), data[index], ...);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at `each`, see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each)

I quote:

> Invokes the specified function for each element in the current selection

I set up a fiddle (watch console) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/keuagq4a/)

Comment: also found this some minutes ago, which is funny cause i was interested in this for some days. Only thing I dislike that I am forced to use d3.select(this) which looks a bit crap.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov do you happen to have a fiddle or something with an example of what you are trying to do? But great, that you found .each too :)

Comment: but then again I cant put this to some function :) and this is crucial cause there is not just append, but append('g').selectAll('.point').enter().append ... and use of 2-dim array data in the end. But ok, i think I am satisfied with each for now and we can close this.

Comment: you can do all of that without each, as I understand your case. If you find time, you can set up another fiddle with data a bit closer to your use-case and I can see that I can help with that. But it is definitely possible to nest these things (just hard to keep track of all the variables and updates :) )